# MySQL JPA query with large number of columns runs much slower than expected

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have query which runs slowly when I am executing it via JPA, the plain mysql call needs ~0.05 seconds, via JPA it takes over 3 seconds and i dont understand why.
The logger shows, that it has a long ObjectBuildingTime:

```
    number of objects=953,
total time=2673045667,
local time=2673045667,
profiling time=1273000,
Timer:Logging=616666,
Timer:ObjectBuilding=2317873662,
Timer:SqlPrepare=16289334,
Timer:Register=149633998,
Timer:StatementExecute=82975667,
Timer:Caching=82966350,
Timer:RowFetch=223775000,
time/object=2804874,
```

What does it mean and how can I speed this up?
My query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TESTENTITY t0, INNERTESTENTITY t1 WHERE (((t0.TIMESTAMPCREATION BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (t0.DATA_TYPE IS NOT NULL)) AND ((t1.ID = t0.ID)))
```

The Innertestentity has many attributes (~40) and two ForeignKeys to other, smaller objects. It is a mapped superclass from Testentity. Can this be the reason?
Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: 
My Entities look like

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DATA_TYPE")
public class TestEntity{
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Employee_ID")
    private EmployeeEntity employeeEntity;
```

And

```
@Entity
@MappedSuperclass
@DiscriminatorValue("SURVEYDATA")
public class innertestEntity extents TestEntity{
    private List<Integer> counts;
    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "statename")
    @Column(name = "value")
    @CollectionTable(name = "states")
    private List<Integer> states;
    private List<String> namelist;
```

Comment: Could you check your fetching strategy? Lazy or eager? It could be the issue

Comment: Following Echo's comment. An eager loading of the related entities (those foreign keys) would transform that query into a `from testentity left join foreigntable1 left join foreigntable2`

Comment: I just edited my question. As far as I understand I have only a relation to EmployeeEntity, which hast fetchType.Lazy

Comment: Turn on logging to see the SQL queries that are generated while building the results. An element collection to another table isn't going to be overly efficient either, but it entirely depends on your database environment/data/tuning etc.  You can try the batchFetch annotation (https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_batchfetch.htm) and/or query hint to reduce the number of queries to this table, but will have to test what works best for your application.

Comment: Can you write down what sql query is generated? Is it possible to reduce this to a complete example where the table has fewer columns? Is your test query doing the same amount of work as the JPA query or is that one fetching more data and e.g. joining other tables? Do you have indexes for your keys?

Comment: Yes, I have indexes. I turned on logging and it creates exactly the expected SQL query: SELECT * FROM TESTENTITY t0, INNERTESTENTITY t1 WHERE (((t0.TIMESTAMPCREATION BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (t0.DATA_TYPE IS NOT NULL)) AND ((t1.ID = t0.ID)))
I also tried batch fetching but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on SQL query debugging in the logs to see if it tells you anything interesting, in your application.properties:

```
org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

You can also try turning on MySQL's slow-query-log which may also be informative, in your MySQL config file (probably /etc/my.cnf ):

```
slow-query-log                  = 1
slow-query-log-file             = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

I suspect the problem may be that some of these other objects (like EmployeeEntity) are being loaded (which could be the case if your code is accessing those fields). Between these logs and your code, I think you'll see if something more is being accessed and loaded.